# Вывод сотых числа после запятой

Tags: php

Как сделать чтобы после полученного значения, если оно целое или один знак после запятой, выводились 1 или 2 нуля в зависимости от числа?

[UPD]Все оказалось гораздо проще: sprintf("%.02f",$ostatok)

Comment: Напишите пример того, какое у вас начальное значение, и какое значение должно получится.

Comment: Сейчас вывод значения так: echo round($ostatok,2); Выводит 2 знака после запятой. Но если значение равно например: 12500 или 12500.1 то хотелось бы чтобы добавлялся .00 или 0 до сотых.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$value = 10;
echo sprintf("%.2f" . "</br>", $value);

$value = 10.3;
echo sprintf("%.2f" . "</br>\n", $value);

$value = 10.23;
echo sprintf("%.2f" . "</br>\n", $value);

?>

Вывод:
10.00
10.30
10.23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it

<?php
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```